# const function in C++

Tags: c++

```
const Integer opeator+(const Integer& left, const Integer& right){

    return Integer(letf.i + left.right);
}
```

Why does the function return non-const object Integer if type of function is **const** Integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the function return non-const object Integer if type of function is const Integer?

It *does* return a constant `Integer`, that is a *copy* of the `Integer` rvalue inside the function body. Also notice that you probably meant to say `right.i` instead of `left.right`, `operator+` instead of `opeator+` and `left.i` instead of `letf.i`.

Answer (score 3):

The function is returning a copy of the `Integer` specified in the `return` statement.  It doesn't matter if the value is `const` or not, since it is being copied into a `const Integer`.

It is similar to this:

```
const Integer result = Integer(5);
```

The `Integer` on the right side doesn't need to be const, since its value is being copied into `result`.

Comment: `const Integer result = Integer(5);` wont invoke the copy constructor but will result in `const Integer(5);`.

Comment: @user3425832 Yes in your case (not in the context of this answere), it is a temporary object, however it is not const. You dont need a const object to copy construct a const object. For clarification: `Foo obj; const Foo& constRef = obj;` is valid code (you can take a const reference to a non-const object, because it wont result in violation of constness). Copy constructors are usually defined as: `Foo(const Foo& other);`, thus this is valid code: `Foo obj1; const Foo obj2;` - `Foo copy1(obj1); Foo copy2(obj2);` - `const Foo(obj1); const Foo(obj2);` Im sorry for the formatting ;)  .

Comment: @Paranaix: It's true that typically the compiler will elide the copy as an optimization; however, logically it is copied.  For example, if the Integer's copy constructor was deleted or private, then it wouldn't compile.